# monitoring js errors

Tags: javascript

I am interested in monitoring javascript errors and logging the errors with the callstack.

I am not interested to wrap everything in try-catch blocks.

According to this article http://blog.errorception.com/2011/12/call-stacks-in-ie.html
it's possible inside window.onerror "*recursively call .caller for each function in the stack to know the previous function in the stack*"

I tried to get the callstack:

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber)
{
    var stk = [], clr = arguments.callee.caller;
    while(clr)
    {
        stk.push("" + clr);
        clr = clr.caller;
    }
    // Logging stk
    send_callstack_to_log(stk);
}
```

but only one step is possible even if the callstack was much longer:

```
(function()
{
function inside() {it.will.be.exception;};
function middle() {inside()};
function outside() {middle()}
outside();
})();
```

One step isn't interesting because onerror arguments give me even more information about it.

Yes, I tried it with IE according the article I mentioned above.

Remark: I also tried to open an account on "ERRORCAEPTION" to gather error log. I tested it with IE and "ERRORCAEPTION" recognize that the errors are coming from IE, but I can't find any callstack information in the log I've got there.

Comment: You might take a look at [stacktrace.js](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace). It is a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Quick update for people stumbling on this in 2019+: This isn't really a problem anymore. All common modern browsers are capable of producing a reliable stack trace, and [the usage of `callee` on functions is restricted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee). You can generate a stack with either [console.trace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace) or by throwing and catching an error. If you want to see when errors happen in production, services like [TrackJS Error Monitoring](https://trackjs.com) can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this log will not always be available, it lacks line numbers, you can not really rely on it.

Try https://qbaka.com

Qbaka automatically overload bunch of JavaScript functions like `addEventListener`, `setTimeout`, `XMLHtppRequest`, etc so that errors happening in callbacks are *automatically* wrapped with try-catch and you will get stacktraces without any code modification.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:
https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace

That's the one I use on [Muscula](http://muscula.com), a service like trackjs.

Comment: I've seen this one. It doesn't help me inside window.onerror. Inside try-catch it's easy to get the stack, but as I told in my question - I can't wrap everything in try-catch blocks. But thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **atatus** which provides javascript contextual error tracking: https://www.atatus.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a program to monitor js error. maybe it will help.

I used three kind of methods to catch exceptions, such as window.onerror, rewrite console.error and window.onunhandledrejection. So I can get Uncaught error, unhandled promise rejection and Custom error

Take a look here: https://github.com/a597873885/webfunny_monitor

or here: https:www.webfunny.cn

It will be help